# Setting up Cron jobs for Laravel on Hostinger's hpanel

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a Laravel project that is already deployed on a live server using Hostinger's web service. I have a task scheduled to run every minute that will basically check if there are organizations that have already expired subscription dates, which will revert their subscription type back to "Free". I tried it first on my local machine and it works great.

However, when I tried to implement this task scheduling in Hostinger, it doesn't work.

I followed [Laravel's official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler) for running a Scheduler on a live server. Since Hostinger [doesn't allow special characters](https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/5646919-how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-with-special-characters-at-hostinger), I created a bash file containing the artisan run command with special characters following their article.

Here's the content of my created bash file:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/u482004401/domains/caviom.org/public_html/artisan && php artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

app/Console/Kernel.php:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {

        CharitableOrganization::whereDate('subscription_expires_at', '>=', now())
            ->update([
                'subscription' => 'Free',
                'subscribed_at' => null,
                'subscription_expires_at' => null
            ]);
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

When I try to view the output of my cron job in Hostinger, it just shows a generic message of a list of artisan commands.

[image]

I have test data on my database that should be updated with this Cron job, but it did not change at all. Has anyone successfully tried setting up cron jobs on Hostinger for a Laravel project?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I wrote the wrong syntax. I fixed it by replacing my bash file:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/u482004401/domains/caviom.org/public_html/artisan && php artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

with

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/php /home/u482004401/domains/caviom.org/public_html/artisan schedule:run
```

Once I saw that the output is now what I expected, I then returned back the

```
/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I don't under stand what you are saying???

Answer (score 0):

This command you need to run by going inside **Cronjobs** section inside **Advanced** dropdown of your Hpanel hosting

```
/usr/bin/php /home/u2xxxxx/full_domain_path/artisan schedule:run
```